# selecting 33% begin, middle & end portion of a groupy object in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below.
I wnat to do the groupby of "Cycle" & "Type". After the groupby is done, i want to perform several actions (sum, mean, var, std, rolling mean, lingress......) on the first 33%, middle 33% and end 33%. how do i do it?
With `head()` & `tail()` i can select only first & last few rows (that too if I know the numbers of rows i need & since length of each group varies, i do not know these values). So, can anyone guide?

```html
Cycle Type Time Values
2 2 101 20.402
2 2 102 20.402
2 2 103 20.402
2 2 104 20.402
2 2 105 20.402
2 2 106 20.383
2 2 107 20.383
2 2 108 20.383
2 2 109 20.383
2 2 110 20.383
2 2 111 20.36
2 2 112 20.36
2 2 113 20.36
2 2 114 20.36
2 2 115 20.36
2 2 116 20.36
2 2 117 20.36
2 2 118 20.36
2 2 119 20.36
2 2 120 20.36
2 2 121 20.348
2 2 122 20.348
2 2 123 20.348
2 2 124 20.348
2 2 125 20.348
3 1 126 20.34
3 1 127 20.34
3 1 128 20.34
3 1 129 20.34
3 1 130 20.34
3 1 131 20.337
3 1 132 20.337
3 1 133 20.337
3 1 134 20.337
3 1 135 20.337
3 1 136 20.342
3 1 137 20.342
3 1 138 20.342
3 1 139 20.342
3 1 140 20.342
3 1 141 20.342
3 1 142 20.342
3 1 143 20.342
3 1 144 20.342
3 1 145 20.342
3 1 146 20.335
3 1 147 20.335
3 1 148 20.335
3 1 149 20.335
5 2 102 20.402
5 2 103 20.402
5 2 104 20.402
5 2 105 20.402
5 2 106 20.383
5 2 107 20.383
5 2 108 20.383
5 2 109 20.383
5 2 110 20.383
5 2 111 20.36
5 2 112 20.36
5 2 113 20.36
5 2 114 20.36
5 2 115 20.36
5 2 116 20.36
5 2 117 20.36
5 2 118 20.36
5 2 119 20.36
```

**Update** result achieved based on suggestion from Valenteno
[image]

Comment: `Time` is monotonic increasing on each `Cycle`. It means groupby of `Cycle` & `Time` creating groups having only one row each.  Doing `first 33%, middle 33% and end 33%` on the these groups doesn't sound right.

Comment: I guess he probably want to group over `Cycle` and `Type`.

Comment: yes. i mean `Cycle` & `Type`. I have correct it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be close to what you want. Here I use only `sum` and `mean`, feel free to add other function to the `agg` argument list.

```
def sample(x):
    aggrfunc = ['sum', 'mean']
    first = x.iloc[0:len(x)//3].agg(aggrfunc)
    middle = x.iloc[len(x)//3:2*len(x)//3].agg(aggrfunc)
    last = x.iloc[2*len(x)//3:].agg(aggrfunc)
    return pd.concat([first, middle, last], keys=['top 33%', 'middle 33%', 'bottom 33%']))

ddf = df.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type']).apply(sample)
```

Using your sample dataframe, this code produces `ddf`:

```
                            Cycle  Type    Time      Values
Cycle Type                                                 
2     2    top 33%    sum    16.0  16.0   836.0  163.159000
                      mean    2.0   2.0   104.5   20.394875
           middle 33% sum    16.0  16.0   900.0  162.926000
                      mean    2.0   2.0   112.5   20.365750
           bottom 33% sum    18.0  18.0  1089.0  183.180000
                      mean    2.0   2.0   121.0   20.353333
3     1    top 33%    sum    24.0   8.0  1036.0  162.711000
                      mean    3.0   1.0   129.5   20.338875
           middle 33% sum    24.0   8.0  1100.0  162.726000
                      mean    3.0   1.0   137.5   20.340750
           bottom 33% sum    24.0   8.0  1164.0  162.708000
                      mean    3.0   1.0   145.5   20.338500
5     2    top 33%    sum    30.0  12.0   627.0  122.374000
                      mean    5.0   2.0   104.5   20.395667
           middle 33% sum    30.0  12.0   663.0  122.229000
                      mean    5.0   2.0   110.5   20.371500
           bottom 33% sum    30.0  12.0   699.0  122.160000
                      mean    5.0   2.0   116.5   20.360000
```

Comment: i need to get all of these as new columns in the original dataframe

Comment: i wanted to say "i need to get all of these to a new dataframe(which already exists) which has only one line for each group."

Comment: I ended up doing like below for each of the item i wanted to calculate. It works but seems too long. I have put the result what I achieved as a pic in the question as well. if you have a better suggestion, please let me know . Thanks for the guidance. `def fm(x):
    first_mean = x.iloc[0:len(x)//3].agg('mean')
    return first_mean
grouped_data['fm']= data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type'])['Detrended'].apply( lambda x: fm(x))`

Comment: Could you edit your question to add a sample of the dataframe which already exists? Will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `cumcount` and `transform` with floor division

```
g=df.groupby(['Cycle','Time'])
s=g.cumcount()//(g.Cycle.transform('count')//3).clip(upper=2)
df.groupby([df.Cycle,df.Time,s]).apply(Yourfunctionhere)
```

Comment: I want to groupby with both 'Cycle' & 'Time'. Also, creating a new dataframe with 33% of the data would be more prefereble

Comment: @mohanys check the update , also for 33.3% it is hard , for example you only have 7 , my method will return 11, 11,111 which is close to what you need

Comment: yes. exact 33% may be difficult & in my case that much precision is not needed either. the data  have is much larger (~2k-3k items in each group) so one or 2 items variation is ok.

Comment: @mohanys then you can check my method :-) , I think that will work

Comment: i need to get the result of my function to a new dataframe(which already exists) which has only one line for each group.

Comment: I am unable to make your code work. may be becasue i do not understand what it is doing. I tried printing g & s. g doesn't print & s prints only 'NaN's. I may try apply different function to each of 33% data. in your solution i am unable to get 33% data out first.

Comment: @mohanys `df.groupby([df.Cycle,df.Time,s]). Values .agg(['mean','sum'])
` also kindly check The data you show to us, if you groupby "Cycle" & "Type" since they are unique combination (in your sample of df), which means you will only have one line for each group